# Umbraco Back Office not showing tree properly

Tags: umbraco7

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the umbraco back-office. The umbraco version is 7.5.3. Inside umbraco back-office when i try to open a node of Settings or Users tab , either templates, partialviews, stylesheets, etc, automatically a .aspx file is generated and downloaded and the node gets loading infinitely. For example clicking Create in templates a file create.aspx is generated and downloaded. Clicking in any of the templates a file EditView.aspx is generated and downloaded.

In chrome console appear the following:
jquery.min.js?cdv=865237568:3 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:54531/umbraco/settings/Views/EditView.aspx?treeType=templates&templateID=3289".

The same problem happen both in back-office local environment and back-office production environment. Fortunately the page in production has not problem but I can't access into the nodes into the back-office. Please, any help would be very appreciated.  At the end, an image of the logs. Any other information required about the issue please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tracking in version control I realized that I had deactivated the ImageProcessor module by commenting the following line in web.config:

```
<!--<add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web" />-->
```

but this line:

```
<add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

which was added previously when I installed ImageProcessor.Web.Config also was necessary to comment it. so I commented too and the problem dissapeared.